# Springboot Maven Run Error: Unresolved reference: FileSizeLimitExceededException

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, kotlin

I'm try to run my SpringBoot maven project using Kotlin Language using

```
mvnw spring-boot:run
```

, but i got below error :

[image]

Here is my code in line [14,62]

```
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.FileSizeLimitExceededException
```

And in line [44,xx]

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = [(FileSizeLimitExceededException::class)]) ==>this is line 44
    @Throws(MultipartException::class)
    fun handleFileSizeLimitExceededException(e: MultipartException, response: HttpServletResponse) {
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE.value(), "The file exceeds its maximum permitted size.")
    }
```

i had try to find the solution, but not found anything,

Am i missing something? I would be glad for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In `application.properties` file write this:

## Max file size.

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=1Mb
```

## Max request size.

```
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=10Mb
```

set it according to your need.

**Update**
**Note: As of Spring Boot 2, however you can now do**

## Max file size.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=1MB
```

## Max request size.

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
```

Comment: thanks for your respond, btw i already set it at application.properties, when error happen